# Streams implementation in C#

Tags: c#, stream, custom-action

*What do I have to do to implement my own stream, **which uses custom compression routine**, similiar to, for example, [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)?*

I obviously have to subclass the `Stream` class, but which methods should be implemented by me and which methods can be left with their default implementations?

Basically speaking, there is a special part of documentation, **but maybe there is a better and easier option?**

> Notes to Implementers
>
> When implementing a derived class of Stream, you
> must provide implementations for the Read and Write methods. The
> asynchronous methods BeginRead, EndRead, BeginWrite, and EndWrite are
> implemented through the synchronous methods Read and Write. Similarly,
> your implementations of Read and Write will work correctly with the
> asynchronous methods. The default implementations of ReadByte and
> WriteByte create a new single-element byte array, and then call your
> implementations of Read and Write. When deriving from Stream, if you
> have an internal byte buffer, it is strongly recommended that you
> override these methods to access your internal buffer for
> substantially better performance. You must also provide
> implementations of CanRead, CanSeek, CanWrite, Flush, Length,
> Position, Seek, and SetLength.
>
> Do not override the Close method, instead, put all of the Stream
> cleanup logic in the Dispose method. For more information, see
> Implementing a Dispose Method.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  The documentation on MSDN is quite clear - are you asking whether Microsoft are deliberately hiding a secret, easier way to create a new implementation of Stream?

Comment: @AdeStringer Well, actually, it's not a problem. But usually asking questions on `stackoveflow` results in better ways of solving problems and in many different things to think of. *Basically, the same thing happened here after @MarcGravell 's answer when I ended up thinking about using `throw` in methods like `Seek()` and thinking about the `sync/async`-related design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods you **must** override are `abstract`. It will not compile until you have implemented them all. However, you are allowed to throw a `NotSupportedException`, for example if you return `false` for `CanSeek`, then `Seek()` is allowed to throw. Likewise if your stream is read-only (reports `false` for `CanWrite`) then it can throw from `Write`.

In reality, for a complex case like this, I expect you'll end up overriding most of the (non-async) API.